# Unselect a row in Feature Table in ARCgis Javascript

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have a `Feature Table` and I am using the `clearSelection()` method to clear the selection on the corresponding `Feature Layer` but that does not clear the row selected in the table.  Looking at the API I don't see a method to deselect a row.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use that same method on the feature table.  If you take a look at their sample in the sandbox editor here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=featuretable .  You can add it to their on('row-select') to test it and see it work.  Something like this as an example:

```
 myFeatureTable.on("row-select", function(evt){
   console.log("select event - ", evt[0].data);
   // Just to demonstrate
   setTimeout(function () {
     myFeatureTable.clearSelection();
   }, 4000)
 });
```

This will then trigger the `deselect` and `filter` event.

EDIT:  Just an FYI, their API leaves out supported methods occasionally. If you do a `console.dir(myFeatureTable);` and look in the `__proto__` and you will see extra methods.

Comment: The FYI EDIT was especially helpful.